# Unintuitive MixedContent error trace on my personal website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mixed-content

I have a portfolio website (https://github.com/ltbd78/portfolio) deployed on GitHub Pages (https://ltbd78.github.io/portfolio) and served on google domains (http://linsuhan.com). The insecure **http**://linsuhan.com site works fine but the secure **https**://linsuhan.come gets the following three MixedContent errors:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://linsuhan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://linsuhan.com/static/js/main.a0793265.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://linsuhan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://linsuhan.com/static/css/main.f8417732.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://linsuhan.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://linsuhan.com/logo-l.png'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I've been scratching my head the whole week on trying to debug where exactly exactly in my source code is this error trace coming from since I'm using ReactJS and the final build `.js` `.css` files differ drastically from the src `.jsx` and `.scss` files.

Is there a way to find out which line in my source code does this error reference?

Comment: One guess I have is https://linsuhan.com is requesting the insecure http://linsuhan.com/static/js/main.a0793265.js when the secure https://linsuhan.com/static/js/main.a0793265.js exists. Perhaps it's not the content of the .js file but rather the the address. How do I have the google domain reference the https:// js file rather than the http:// js file?

Comment: Your page embeds the script via the URL `https://ltbd78.github.io/portfolio/static/js/main.a0793265.js`, but that gets automatically redirected to `http://linsuhan.com/static/js/main.a0793265.js` - so this is likely an issue with your setup on the github side of things.

Comment: And `https://linsuhan.com` does not get served using a valid SSL certificate for that domain either, the certificate is for `*.github.io` - so people will not be able to access this directly, their browsers will show a warning, and ask them if they explicitly want to go to the site nevertheless.

Comment: That's a good point. Do you have any idea why it's getting redirected? Would "Enforce HTTPS" and waiting 24 hours help in any way? I've only tried that option and waited 4 hours with no luck.

Comment: Got something do to with your domain setup on github, I suppose. You will either have to fix that, so that it redirect to the HTTPS version at least - or see if you can't make your system use/generate relative URLs to begin with. Would avoid the additional redirect, so better for loading times.

Comment: By relative URL could this potentially be because of React's `<MemoryRouter>`?